# Extension can't do ajax request

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to manipulate a web page based on answer of ajax request. Basicly I'll search title of page in youtube and retrieve first youtube.

```
var search_input = $("#title").text();
var keyword= encodeURIComponent(search_input);
// Youtube API 
var yt_url='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q='+keyword+'&format=5&max-results=1&v=2&alt=jsonc'; 

$.ajax
({
type: "GET",
url: yt_url,
dataType:"jsonp",
success: function(response)
{

console.log("succeded");

if(response.data.items)
{
$.each(response.data.items, function(i,data)
{
var video_id=data.id;
var video_title=data.title;
var video_viewCount=data.viewCount;
// IFRAME Embed for YouTube
var video_frame="<iframe src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/"+video_id+"' frameborder='0' type='text/html'></iframe>";

var final="<div>"+video_frame+"</div><div id='count'>"+video_viewCount+" Views</div>";

$("#videos").html(final); // Result

});
}
else
{
$("#videos").html("<div id='no'>No Video</div>");
}
}
});
```

And here's manifest.json

```
{
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "https://*.website.com/*",
                "*://*.youtube.com/*"
            ],
            "js": [
                "jquery.js",
                "mymanipulatır.js"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "name": "Name",
    "icons": {
        "128": "128x128.png"
    },
    "homepage_url": "http://github.com/",
    "version": "1.4",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "developer": {
        "name": "may"
    },
    "description": "youtube"
}
```

Extension throws `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery11100021788313053548336_1393869626682 is not defined` when trying to make ajax request. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

When doing cross-site XHR's from a content script injected into a web page, you need to declare the url patterns you want to be able to connect to in the "permissions" section of your manifest the same way as if you were doing the XHR from inside one of your extensions own standalone pages (eg the background page, a browser action popup, etc.).

See: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr